# Extracting Specific Information from Scientific Papers

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, information-extraction

I am looking for specific information that I need to extract from scientific papers. The information mostly resides in the "Evaluation" or "Implementation" sections of the papers. I need to extract any function name, parameter, file name, application name, application version in the content.
Is there any NLP technique/machine learning algorithm to do this type of information extraction from scientific papers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf applications that do this specific task (although that does not mean there isn't one, and there may be commercial solutions to do this). But there are open source options that would probably allow you to do what you want with a bit of work (annotation and/or rule-writing):

- [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/) (has a "user-friendly" graphical interface so you don't need to code if you don't want to)
- [Reverb](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/)
- [Stanford OpenIE](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html)
- [Canary](http://canary.bwh.harvard.edu/) (geared towards clinical NLP by the looks of it, but could be more generally applicable)
- [GROBID](https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid) (this looks like it could be of use to segment the articles into sections)

Alternatively, you could build your own solution on top of libraries like [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) or [spaCy](http://spacy.io/) (if you code in Python) or [Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html) (Java). It sounds like you would need to first identify document sections and then search for patterns within them. Whether you adopt a machine learning or rule-based approach, this will probably take a fair bit of work. If you have a predefined list of items you are looking for, that will make your life far easier!